# Magento - Add Product Expiry Date for Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom

Our store has few customer groups based on their purchase. We have a requirement where the admin will enter the product expiry date i.e start/end date which will be shown on the product detail page. Consider below case

```
Product A
Start date 01-JAN-2016
End date 31-JAN-2016

Product B
Start date 01-JAN-2016
End date 29-FEB-2016
```

Once the expiry date is over, the product should not be visible on the frontend for a specific customer group.

As shown in the below image for Magento default Group Price, there will be a custom attribute where admin can set product expiry `(start/end)` date according to `customer group`.

[image: group price]

Below is the sample image of how it should look like

[image: group_1]

I have created two date fields for expiry as a custom attribute but do not know how to set them for customer groups

How do I approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Such feature represents some work and I do not know if anyone has already done it but here is my suggestion:

- First, I suggest you look at the following extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-restriction-based-on-customer-group.html You can probably modify it so it uses a date field to add an expiry date to the limitation.
- Second, you can probably implement such feature by learning the implementation of the group prices in Magento. Based on this, I'm sure you can replicate a similar system with expiry dates.

Comment: Date fields are created as product attributes. But the issue is how to integrate them with customer groups ? Unaware of extending group price feature of magento